# Handling packets through server causes big CPU increase

Tags: java, networking, udp

I have an UDP server which receives audio streams from multiple clients and it must be rerouted to the correct client. The problem which I have is that when 2 clients exchange audio stream with each other then it increases my computer CPU usage by a lot. Even 6 clients that exchange audio between each other makes my CPU usage go as high as 50% and can go all the way up to 100% and a server like this should handle over hundred clients easily.

Because we stream audio it will receive probably thousands of udp packets per second and in order for the packets to receive at their correct client destination I loop through an hashmap for each client so it arrives correctly. Now I suspect that this is probably the cause of the huge CPU usage, is there another better way to know the client destination instead of iterating through an hashmap for each client?

Below is my code where I redistribute my packets:

```
    for (Map.Entry<Session, Integer> entry : sessions.entrySet()) {
                    Session key = entry.getKey();
                    int value = entry.getValue(); // session ID

                    // send packets from client1 to client2
                    
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            
                            if (key.player1.getIp() == ip) {
                                
                                DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length,
                                        key.player2.getIp(), key.player2.getPort());

                                try {
                                    socket1.send(dp);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    });
                    thread.start();

                    // send packets from client2 to client1
                    if (key.player2.getIp() == ip) {
                        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length,
                                key.player1.getIp(), key.player1.getPort());

                        try {
                            socket1.send(dp);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Session:

```
class Session {

//two initialized player objects per session
Player1 player1 = new Player1();
Player2 player2 = new Player2();

class Player1 {
    
    private InetAddress ip;
    private int port;
    
    public InetAddress getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(InetAddress ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    
}

class Player2 {
    
    private InetAddress ip;
    private int port;
    
    public InetAddress getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(InetAddress ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1

You "loop through a hashmap".  The sole point of using a hashmap is to be able to look things up by hashing.

Arrange your data structures to fit the requirements of your algorithm. It seems you're looking up by IP.  OK, so you need a hash map from IP to something.

Your current hashmap looks on the surface to be designed backwards. The key is a 'session', which I suppose to be a moderately complex structure.  The value for that key is a simple integer session id.  You don't need a map at all for that: store the id in the session object.

A map from id to session would make some sort of sense, although doesn't seem to quite meet your current needs.  But there's no rule that you must have only one map.  It's legitimate, and possibly useful, to keep id-to-session *and* IP-to-session maps.   Perhaps even an IP-to-session-partner map.

Data structure design is often more important than code.

Problem 2

You create a thread for every entry in the hashmap. Most of those threads will be 'not the intended IP' and do nothing.  The check should be before creating the thread.

Thread creation is expensive and you don't want to be running hundreds of threads to service hundreds of clients. You need a better model, for example with some reasonable number of threads servicing queued requests.

---

If I were designing this, I think the core of the solution would look like this, in pseudocode:

```
/**
 * Process datagram from 'addr' by sending to partner
 */
void forward(datagram dg, ipaddr from) {
    session sess = addr_to_session_map.get(from);
    session other = sess.other;
    send_datagram(dg, from, other.ipaddr);
}
```

That is to say, when I receive a datagram, I find its session object from a single map lookup on source address.  The session is cross-linked to its partner (it seems from your description that they are paired one-to-one, though that's a simple enough change if I'm wrong).

No loops needed. The overhead is constant for any given client.

Comment: So for the first problem your suggesting i would create a collection of InetAdresses

Comment: Depends on your terms. I'd consider a Map<IP, Session> to be a collection of Sessions, indexed by IP. Why that way?  Because Session is what I'm interested in, and IP is what I am given to find the right Session.  But yeah,  lookup by IP address is where to start.

Comment: I have included a class file Session i beleave it be a more efficient way of just iterating through an IPaddress for my particular application. The <IP, Session> doesn't work unfortuanetly i tried that in the past. I have also added Session class in code if you wanna check it out. And honnestly maybe there is no error in the code but it may just be that streaming audio through udp is just CPU expensive on the server part. When i connect 70 clients the cpu usage goes up to 50% even with high latency on the buffer.

Comment: You keep saying "iterating", which is the cause of your problems. An appropriate data structure avoids the need to iterate.  Suppose you are looking for one IP address in a collection of 'N' such.  On average, iteration requires N/2 operations -- that is, it's O(N).. A map lookup, with appropriate map parameters, requires 1 operation; it is O(1).  You should free yourself of the misconception that 'iteration' is the way to locate a data structure.

Comment: Hmmm, but il test that code that you wrote and il update you on how it went.

Comment: Ok so here is the update: I have managed to recreate the code using <IP, Session> without any loops and it wasn't even that hard to be honest. By using IP i efficiently can lookup in what session the user is in. But CPU wise: I have ran 70 clients on both the version where i lookup by IP and by looking through looping and the conclussion was that both versions of the client use almost exactly the same amount of CPU. Altough i will use the new code because it is less writing and generally more efficiently writen. If you are kind enough you can let me know why the CPU hasn't changed much.

Comment: You mean "the same amount of CPU for the same client load" ?  If so, what that means is either (a) the bottleneck is somewhere else (b) there is some irreducible minimum on processing.

Comment: I mean the the CPU where the server is being hosted on. Not the the client side.

Comment: Have you tested you server under the expected load? Right now you're only guessing that there is a problem. It might be that the process that is measuring your cpu load is incorrect.